# Generate quartz crone schedule

Tags: cron, scheduler, job-scheduling

I want to generate a quartz crone schedule that will run only once or run after 1 hour and end in 3 hours.

```
"MyJob": { 
        "Enabled": true,
        "CronSchedules": [ "0 0 * ? * *" ] // EVERY HOUR
      },
```